# Can you set Details for Videos with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a NAS to which I Rip most of my DVD's. The problem comes with series. When I have to RIP a season, the Details (Title, Comments, etc) must be manually entered.

To combat this, I wrote the following script:

```
$array = @() 
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\Videos\Dead Like Me\*.mpg' ).FullName |
foreach{
   $array += $_ 
   }
$i = 0
Do  {
    $Episode = $i + 1
    $NewName = "Dead Like Me S1E$Episode.mpg"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $array[$i] -Name "Title" -Value $NewName
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $array[$i] -Name "Comments" -Value $NewName
    Rename-Item -Path $array[$i] -NewName $NewName
$i += 1
} While ($i -lt $array.length)
```

It seems that Set-ItemProperty does not recognize the Title nor Comments, not other properties from the "Details" tab for the file.

I've also tried

```
Get-ChildItem $array[$i] | Set-ItemProperty -Name "Title" -Value $NewName
```

Either way, I get an error similar to the following:

> Set-ItemProperty : The property string Title=Dead Like Me S1 D1 E3.mpg
>   does not exist or was not found.
>       At c:\Videos\Dead Like Me\tmp.ps1:20 char:30
>   + ... ChildItem $array[$i] | Set-ItemProperty -Name "Title" -Value $NewName
>   +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (string Title=Dead Like Me S1 D1 E3.mpg:PSNoteProperty) [Set-ItemProperty], I    OException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetPropertyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

Shouldn't Set-ItemProperty be able to address those properties?

@trebleCode Update

I ran the following:

```
get-itemproperty "C:\Videos\Dead Like Me\video.mpg" | Format-List -Property * -Force
```

It returns:

```
 PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Video\Dead Like Me\video.mpg 
 PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Video\Dead Like Me Renamer 
 PSChildName       : video.mpg 
 PSDrive           : C 
 PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem Mode              : -a----
 VersionInfo       : 
                     File: C:\Video\Dead Like Me\video.mpg
                     InternalName:
                     OriginalFilename:
                     FileVersion:
                     FileDescription:
                     Product:
                     ProductVersion:
                     Debug:            False
                     Patched:          False
                     PreRelease:       False
                     PrivateBuild:     False
                     SpecialBuild:     False
                     Language:

 BaseName          : video 
 Target            : {} 
 LinkType          :
 Name              : video.mpg 
 Length            : 321536 
 DirectoryName     : C:\Video\Dead Like Me 
 Directory         : C:\Video\Dead Like Me 
 IsReadOnly        : False 
 Exists            : True 
 FullName          : C:\Video\Dead Like Me\video.mpg
 Extension         : .mpg 
 CreationTime      : 2019-02-04 10:15:51
 CreationTimeUtc   : 2019-02-04 16:15:51 
 LastAccessTime    : 2019-02-04 13:03:31 
 LastAccessTimeUtc : 2019-02-04 19:03:31 
 LastWriteTime     : 2018-07-09 15:00:47 
 LastWriteTimeUtc  : 2018-07-09 20:00:47 
 Attributes        : Archive
```

Comment: If you get the item and output to format-list or format-title, what properties does it expose?

Comment: This is about metadeta not item properties. You call meta data diffrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open source library called [TagLib-Sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/) that supports setting metadata on audio and video files. It's pretty easy to use - there's some sample code at [this blog](http://powershelltidbits.blogspot.com/2016/06/mp4-tv-show-file-tagging-with-powershell.html) - the gist of it is:

```
Import-Module "D:\powershell\modules\MPTag\taglib-sharp.dll"
$BOXTYPE_TVSH = "tvsh"; # TV Show or series
$mediaFile = [TagLib.File]::Create($file.FullName)
[TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag]$customTag = $mediaFile.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Apple, 1)
$customTag.SetText($BOXTYPE_TVSH, $showName)
$mediaFile.Save()
```